# How to keep columns of the same data updated in multiple tables Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table `PaymentAccount` that keeps track of payment accounts. I have instance methods in the `PaymentAccount` that returns if the payment account is "ready" e.g. `account.is_payment_ready?`.

Every time updates are made to the these records, I would like to update another column `payment_ready` in a table called `Profile` with the corresponding boolean value. Instead of querying for `account.is_payment_ready?` whenever profiles are retrieved, I would like to be able to just do `profile.payment_ready` to reduce the # of DB queries.

Note `PaymentAccount` and `Profile` would have a one-to-one association.

My first instinct is to have an `after_commit` hook in the `PaymentAccount` model as such:

```
class PaymentAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :update_profile

    def is_payment_ready?
       if ready
          return true # if ready
       else
          return false # if not ready
       end
    end 

    def update_profile
       self.profile.payment_ready = is_payment_ready?
       self.profile.save
    end
end
```

Would this be the correct approach? Assume that both `Profile` and `PaymentAccount` always exists for a given `User`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Essentially, are you wondering what the best way to update a profile's `payment_ready` column to reflect whatever it's associated payment_account's `ready` column is?

Comment: @mackshkatz yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using a `before_save` rather than an `after_commit` in the case that something went wrong in the saving of the `Profile`, you wouldn't want the two records to get out of sync when the `PaymentAccount` saved but the Profile rolledback for whatever reason. Not to mention, another added benefit is that both updates will happen in the same db transaction.

Also, you get the method #ready? for free from `ActiveRecord`, so you might as well use that rather than writing a method that is essentially just an alias.

So something like:

```
class PaymentAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_profile

  private

  def update_profile
    profile.payment_ready = ready?
    profile.save
  end
end
```